# Raycast With Innaccuracy Sometimes Going Through Target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, raycasting

I'm attempting to make a raycast for a laser that will have some level of inaccuracy when fired. I was doing this with a method that creates a vector3 with some random values and adding it to the forward direction of the object firing the laser. This however seems to occasionally make the raycast clip through the object without hitting it. The code I added is debug testing to figure out this problem.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     Vector3 attackDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward + new Vector3(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

     RaycastHit hit;
     if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, attackDirection, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
     {
         Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, attackDirection * 50);
     }
     Vector3 directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position);

     Aiming(directionToTarget);
     OrbitAroundTarget();
 }
```

1. The object firing the raycast is orbiting around the object it's supposed to be hitting.
2. Both objects have box colliders and rigidbodies that are kenetic.
3. This is also happening if the code is executing in FixedUpdate or Update.
4. The Aiming method makes the object Quaternion.Slerp to look at it's target and the Orbit method makes the object transform.RotateAround it's target.
   [image]

Comment: Can you confirm that the box collider completely covers the target?

Comment: Yes, the box collider covers the whole two boxes.